# Symfony 2.5 namespaces issue

Tags: php, symfony, namespaces

I want to write my own model classes using Doctrine DBAL Layer but I have some problem with namespaces. 
My class is in Models dir int file TestModel.php and has namespace

```
namespace Acme\MyBundle\Models;
```

But in my code I'm using example from DBAL docs

```
$config = new \Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration();
```

I'm getting an error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration' not found in
```

But everything works if I add this code into Entity file with Entity namespace. I deleted vendor dir and made composer update but it still not works. What did I make wrong?

Comment: Try: use Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration; $config = new Configuration;  But it should behave the same as what you posted.  Where are you trying to create $config from?

Comment: I have folder Model and TestModel file there. This file has 
namespace Acme\MyBundle\Model and I have class TestModel and in this class in some method I want to use this DBAL configuration but it returns me an error? Should I register it somewhere, because my code returns me this error
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration' not found in

Comment: How are you running your TestModel?  phpunit?

Comment: I'm using phpStorm 7 and runt there to check if file has some errors, this IDE uses php that is installed in my system.

Comment: I don't include TestModel into other files. I'm just making Run in IDE.

Comment: So does it include app/autoload.php?  If you want to make Symfony 2 oriented tests then you will probably be better off using phpunit the the test framework.  http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/doctrine.html